# Pass a google assistant command from Flutter app

Tags: flutter, iot, google-home, google-assistant

I have a garage door connected to a SONOFF. The sonoff is triggering a relay so when the door is closed, it is opening and when the door is open it is closing it.

Now this can be triggered with google assistant either by sayng (google activate garage, or by typing it to google home app or google assistant).

How can I pass this command to google assistant with a tap of a button in a flutter app?

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/overview) to pass command to Google Assistant with the tap of a button in the Flutter App. The Google Assistant SDK lets you add voice control, natural language understanding and Google’s smarts to your ideas. Your project captures an utterance (a spoken audio request, such as What's on my calendar?), sends it to the Google Assistant, and receives a spoken audio response in addition to the raw text of the utterance.

Comment: cool but i need make it capture a text command